# Showing $\mathbb{H}$ is isomorphic to a subring of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras

Tags: quaternions, algebras

I'm currently trying to show that the ring $A =\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b 
\\
- \bar{b} & \bar{a} 
\end{pmatrix} $ is isomorphic to the real quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

I've already shown that $A$ is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and that its centre is $$Z(A) = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
a & 0 
\\
0 & a
\end{pmatrix} | a \in \mathbb{R} \right\}. $$

Since we are considering $A$ and $\mathbb{H}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, we know that there are structure maps $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow A$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ s.t. $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset Z(A)$ and $g(\mathbb{R}) \subset Z(\mathbb{H}) = \mathbb{R}$.

From what I can gather, I need to show that there's some function $h: A \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ which is a bijective homomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.  And to show it is a homomorphism, I need to show $h \circ f = g$.

And this is where I'm stuck.  I haven't been shown an explicit example of how to show two R-algebras are isomorphic, so a bit confused as to how to go about it all.  Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: $\Bbb H$ is generated as an $\Bbb R$-algebra by $1, i, j, k$ with identities like $i^2 = -1$ and $ij = k$. Find four matrices in $A$ that fulfill the same relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
z=a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{i} \quad  \mapsto \quad \mathbf{Z}= a\mathbf{U}+b\mathbf{I}+c\mathbf{J}+d\mathbf{K} \quad a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}
$$
with:
$$
\mathbf{U}=
\left( 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
1&0  \\
 0 &1
\end{array}
\right)
\qquad
\mathbf{I}=
\left( 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
i&0  \\
 0 &-i
\end{array}
\right)
\qquad
\mathbf{J}=
\left( 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1  \\
 -1 &0
\end{array}
\right)
\qquad
\mathbf{K}=
\left( 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
0&i  \\
 i &0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and:
$$
\mathbf{I}^2=\mathbf{J}^2=\mathbf{K}^2=\mathbf{I}\mathbf{J}\mathbf{K}=-\mathbf{U}
$$
$$
\mbox{det}(\mathbf{Z})=
\left |
\left( 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
 a+ib&c+id  \\
 -c+id &a-ib
\end{array}
\right)
\right |=
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=|z|^2
$$